# Generating weekending dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I want to generate all the weekend dates (Saturdays) for different ID's and their different time ranges.

This is what my data looks like:

```
ID   minDate    MaxDate
-------------------------
101  5/16/2020  9/25/2021
102  8/7/2021   8/21/2021
103  5/1/2021   9/26/2021
```

For `ID = 101`, I would like to return all the week ending dates (Saturdays) starting from 5/16/2020, 5/23/2020, 5/30/2020, 6/6/2020 ..... all the way until 9/25/2021.

And I will need to do the same thing for all the different ID's.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest you do some research on a calendar table. A table that pre-calcs a whole bunch of useful attributes against every single day, including weekends. If you are doing calendar based logic you will liekly eventually need a calendar table.

Comment: Thank you @Nick.Mcdermaid. Since I use that output for my Power BI report, will a dimension calendar table in Power BI do the same trick? I just don't know how to apply the logic with calendar table in power bi.

Comment: It probably would, but you'd be building the logic in M or DAX, rather than SQL. Pick your poison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6d524ead21df74653d7298a8f1eeab2)..

```
select *, dateadd(week, nm.rn-1, dateadd(day, 7-datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst,mindate)), mindate)) as _Saturday
from
(
values
(101, cast('20200516' as date), cast('20210925' as date)),
(102, '20210708', '20210822'),
(103, '20210501', '20210926')
) as t(id,mindate,maxdate)
join
(
    --tally..max 1000 weeks
    select row_number() over(order by @@spid) as rn
    from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as a(n)
    cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as b(n)
    cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as c(n)
) as nm on nm.rn <= datediff(week, mindate, maxdate)+1
where t.maxdate >= dateadd(week, nm.rn-1, dateadd(day, 7-datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst,mindate)), mindate))
order by t.id, nm.rn;
```

Comment: hi @Iptr! Thank you so much for your quick response. Do you mind telling me if I have to do the cast as the date for every row like you did for ID 101?

Comment: ..@XiaofanChen .. if the min/maxdate columns are of date(time) datatype then cast() is not needed. The code could work with char columns (implicitly converted to datetime in the datediff&add() functions) but it is always best to be explicit..for eg 03/04/2021 is 3rd April or 4th March? In case of char min/maxdate columns it would be better to use convert(date,column,style) instead of cast().

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I was able to make a little tweak to let your query work on my table.  And OMG it worked like magic! Many many thanks!! @lptr